# How to achieve automatic updates of chrome extensions outside the chrome web store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension application, and people who use it do not have the network requirements to access the chrome web store. So I can't host the extension to the chrome web store for them to download and use.

So is there any good way to host the chrome extension on your own server, distribute it to macOS/Windows users, and automatically update the application when they use it?

I used chrome://extensions/ to package the extension function in the chrome browser, built two different versions of extensions with the same key, and uploaded them to the local localhost server, but was prompted when downloading: program Invalid package: "CRX_REQUIRED_PROOF_MISSING".

And when I dragged the built crx to chrome://extensions/, it was also prompted: the extension is not listed in the Chrome app store and may have been added without your knowledge.